# Including glossary elements within published HTML/SCORM topics

Tags: xslt, dita-ot

I’m working on modifying our Scorm publishing plugin to embed glossary information within a tooltip, rather than publishing them as separate html files. So far I have been able to get the `<glossterm>` and `<glossdef>` to publish where I want them, but if the definition contains additional elements such as `<ul>` or `<dl>` I just get the content within those elements without the elements and attributes I need in order to style them.

Obviously the logic exists because it does publish that way to the html version of the glossary topic, I’m just having trouble figuring out how to get it to work within my template. Are there message threads or suggestions for other resources I should be checking out?

Thanks,
Mark

Here is a sample of the DITA code in the glossdef:

```xml
<glossdef class="- topic/abstract concept/abstract glossentry/glossdef ">
    A value that describes the types of entries contained within the ACH file and includes: 
    <ul class="- topic/ul ">
    <li class="- topic/li ">
            <p class="- topic/p ">200 - Mixed Debits and Credits</p>
         </li><li class="- topic/li ">
            <p class="- topic/p ">220 - Credits Only</p>
         </li><li class="- topic/li ">
            <p class="- topic/p ">225 - Debits Only</p>
         </li></ul>
</glossdef>
```

Here is what I get in the html output:

```html
<div class="body conbody glossBody"><div class="abstract abstract glossdef">
    A value that describes the types of entries contained within the ACH file and includes: 
            200 - Mixed Debits and Credits
            220 - Credits Only
            225 - Debits Only
</div></div>
```

Here is what I want to html to look like:

```html
<div class="body conbody glossBody"><div class="abstract abstract glossdef">
    A value that describes the types of entries contained within the ACH file and includes: 
      <ul class="ul"><li class="li">
            <p class="p">200 - Mixed Debits and Credits</p>
         </li><li class="li">
            <p class="p">220 - Credits Only</p>
         </li><li class="li">
            <p class="p">225 - Debits Only</p>
         </li></ul>
</div></div>
```

This is the portion of the topic-term template that builds the "tooltip" in the html output:

```xml
<!-- hovertip text -->
        <xsl:variable name="hovertext">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="getMatchingGlossdef">
            <xsl:with-param name="m_matched-target" select="$matched-target"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="m_keys" select="$keys"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:variable>
<!-- End of hovertip text -->
        
<xsl:when test="local-name() = 'term'">
<!-- mgh-2/7/2023 - Beginning of the tooltip anchor tag. -->
            <xsl:element name="a">
              <xsl:attribute name="rel">tooltip</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="class">jTip</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="name">Glossary</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="href">##</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:value-of select="@keyref"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
    <!-- mgh-2/7/2023 - Creates the <dfn> containter for the term and inserts the appropriate text. -->
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="dita-ot:text-only">
                <xsl:with-param name="displaytext" select="normalize-space($displaytext)"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
    <!-- mgh-2/7/2023 - Builds the <div> element to contain the glossary tooltip which will display on mouseover of the term. -->
              <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">tipContent</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="style">display: none;</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="h1">
                  <xsl:attribute name="class">title title glossterm topictitle1</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$displaytext"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="div">
                  <xsl:attribute name="class">body conbody glossBody</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:element name="div">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">abstract abstract glossdef</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$hovertext"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
<!-- End of the tooltip anchor tag. -->
          </xsl:when>
```

This is the template that creates the contents of the "hovertip" which is then displayed when a user hovers over the term. I believe this is what I actually need to modify to get the results I'm looking for. In this specific example I am trying to build an unordered list but it might also be an ordered list or a definition list.

```xml
<xsl:template match="*" mode="getMatchingGlossdef">
    <xsl:param name="m_matched-target"/>
    <xsl:param name="m_keys"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($m_matched-target = '#none#')">
        <xsl:variable name="glossentry"
          select="exsl:node-set($m_matched-target)/*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossentry ')][1]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$glossentry/*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossdef ')]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$glossentry/*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossdef ')]"
              mode="dita-ot:text-only"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when
            test="$glossentry//*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossSurfaceForm ')][normalize-space(.) != '']">
            <!-- Second choice: surface form, as it may contain *slightly* more information than the original term -->
            <xsl:apply-templates
              select="$glossentry//*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossSurfaceForm ')][normalize-space(.) != '']"
              mode="dita-ot:text-only"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Fall back to term if there is no definition and no surface form -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$glossentry//*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossterm ')]"
              mode="dita-ot:text-only"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="
          normalize-space(.) = '' and
          (boolean(ancestor::*[contains(@class, ' topic/copyright ')]) or generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyref', @keyref)[1]))">
        <!-- Already generating a message when looking for the term, do not generate a "missing glossentry" message here too -->
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when
        test="boolean(ancestor::*[contains(@class, ' topic/copyright ')]) or generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyref', @keyref)[1])">
        <!-- Didn't look up term because it was specified, but this is the first occurrence
           and the glossentry was not found, so generate "missing glossentry" message -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="ditamsg:no-glossentry-for-key">
          <xsl:with-param name="matching-keys" select="$m_keys"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: FYI I edited your question to add back tick characters to delimit the code elements in your question. You can't just write HTML embedded in the question or it will not be displayed. I just wanted you to know for the future reference. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You will need to include the XSLT code, I think. You will have to define templates for each type of element within the `glossdef`. Also, how are you displaying the content as a "tooltip"? Do you have "tooltip" formatting defined in CSS that corresponds to one of those `class` attribute values?

Comment: Thank you, @ConalTuohy, for cleaning up the code in my original post, and for the link to the help information on including code blocks within posts. I will post the relevant portions of the XSLT in a separate comment for review. In answer to your question about displaying the content, yes, I do have CSS that corresponds to the class attributes shown in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The template you've included calls some other templates in the `dita-ot:text-only` mode, and presumably it's these templates which are responsible for generate the tooltips that contain text only, without markup. I'd suggest replacing those calls to `apply-templates` in `dita-ot:text-only` mode with calls to new templates (perhaps in the same `getMatchingGlossdef` mode? or a mode called `tooltip`?) which produce the kind of HTML markup you actually want for your tooltips.

It's hard to say exactly what's the best way forward without seeing more of the XSLT, which so far you've only shown a small part (e.g. what those missing templates (in the `dita-ot:text-only` mode) actually do; where the `$keys` and `$matched-target` variables come from, etc).

But without that information, there's one other general comment I'd make about the XSLT code above, which is that it has a very procedural style, and could I think be implemented more concisely and clearly in a more declarative style, replacing `<xsl:choose>`, `<xsl:when>`, etc, with calls to `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, and a set of more specific templates.

For instance, this `choose`:

```xml
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="$glossentry/*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossdef ')]">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$glossentry/*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossdef ')]"
     mode="dita-ot:text-only"/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:when
   test="$glossentry//*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossSurfaceForm ')][normalize-space(.) != '']">
   <!-- Second choice: surface form, as it may contain *slightly* more information than the original term -->
   <xsl:apply-templates
     select="$glossentry//*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossSurfaceForm ')][normalize-space(.) != '']"
     mode="dita-ot:text-only"/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
   <!-- Fall back to term if there is no definition and no surface form -->
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$glossentry//*[contains(@class, ' glossentry/glossterm ')]"
     mode="dita-ot:text-only"/>
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

You have a `when` which evaluates a particular XPath expression, and if it's non-empty, it applies templates to the very same XPath expression. Otherwise it evaluates a second XPath expression, and if it's non-empty, it applies templates to *that* expression. Apart from the fact that there's an obvious duplication of XPath code, there's a more natural way to express this in XSLT, which is to define distinct templates which represent those different options, and put the XPath criteria into those template's `match` attributes. Then you can simply `apply-templates`, and the appropriate matching template will apply.

Comment: Thanks, ```@Conal```, this gives me a place to start. Next week I will begin building separate templates to handle the different scenarios. I'm sure that will be easier to troubleshoot and maintain in the long run. I agree there is a lot of extraneous code here, actually throughout the stylesheet, and I am always looking for ways to clean it up.